# cmbComboBox.SelectionStart always returns zero irrespective of cursor location

Tags: vb.net, combobox

For some reason the "SelectionStart" property behaves differently from TextBox to ComboBox.

Create a TextBox and a ComboBox. Make sure DropDownStyle = DropDown (NOT DropDownList!)

Add these Leave events (same result if you use LostFocus event):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Debug.Print("Textbox:  " & TextBox1.SelectionStart)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
    Debug.Print("ComboBox: " & ComboBox1.SelectionStart)
End Sub
```

Now type text into each control and change focus from control to control, with the selection cursor in different places in the string.

I get this:

```
Textbox:  6
ComboBox: 0
Textbox:  8
ComboBox: 0
Textbox:  5
ComboBox: 0
Textbox:  4
ComboBox: 0
... and so on
```

When the textbox loses focus, it returns the correct SelectionStart.
When the combobox loses focus, it always returns zero.

Is there a reason, solution or reasonable workaround? I cannot seem to intercept this without creating a new variable for each combo control, and storing the SelectionStart on every click and keypress event (assuming the user might click the mouse, use arrow keys or type characters).

Comment: I just tested what you suggested and I didn't see exactly what you described. If I set the caret somewhere other than the beginning of the text in the `ComboBox` then on the first `Leave` event I got the expected value for `SelectionStart`, as well as for `SelectionLength` and `SelectedText`. When the `ComboBox` received focus again though, the entire text was shown as selected, so `SelectionStart`, `SelectionLength` and `SelectedText` reflected that. There's no managed API to control that behaviour but there may be something to be done inside the control. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: I wonder how that's possible? I first noticed this thing using VS2015 and it still occurs (for me at least) in VS2017. I get the whole text highlighted when I focus the control too, but that's not such an issue here. I'm trying to insert text at the caret (I'm assuming this is the term for the blinking text cursor start position bar thing) but I'm currently limited to inserting at 0 or inserting at TextLength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it, using your idea but just setting the value in a different location.

```
Dim ComboSelectionStart As Integer

Private Sub cmbComboBox_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles cmbComboBox.KeyUp
    'Store selection on any key press
    ComboSelectionStart = cmbComboBox.SelectionStart
End Sub

Private Sub cmbComboBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles cmbComboBox.MouseClick
    'Store selection on any mouse click
    ComboSelectionStart = cmbComboBox.SelectionStart
End Sub

Private Sub cmbComboBox_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbComboBox.Leave
    'Returns correct value here because it was not altered by LostFocus event
    Debug.Print(ComboSelectionStart .ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did some testing and it appears that the selection is reset between the `Leave` and `LostFocus` events as well as between the `Enter` and `GotFocus` events.  I tried remembering the values on the first of each pair and restoring it on the second and it worked as desired:

```
Private comboBox1SelectionStart As Integer
Private comboBox1SelectionLength As Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Enter
    comboBox1SelectionStart = ComboBox1.SelectionStart
    comboBox1SelectionLength = ComboBox1.SelectionLength
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
    comboBox1SelectionStart = ComboBox1.SelectionStart
    comboBox1SelectionLength = ComboBox1.SelectionLength
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.GotFocus
    ComboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1SelectionStart
    ComboBox1.SelectionLength = comboBox1SelectionLength
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.LostFocus
    ComboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1SelectionStart
    ComboBox1.SelectionLength = comboBox1SelectionLength
End Sub
```

You don't want to have to do that every time for every `CokmboBox` so you can build it into a custom control and then use that in place of the standard control:

```
Public Class ComboBoxEx
    Inherits ComboBox

    Private selectionStartTemp As Integer
    Private selectionLengthTemp As Integer

    Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnEnter(e)

        'Remember the current selection.
        selectionStartTemp = SelectionStart
        selectionLengthTemp = SelectionLength
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnGotFocus(e As EventArgs)
        'Restore the selection.
        SelectionStart = selectionStartTemp
        SelectionLength = selectionLengthTemp

        MyBase.OnGotFocus(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLeave(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLeave(e)

        'Remember the current selection.
        selectionStartTemp = SelectionStart
        selectionLengthTemp = SelectionLength
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(e As EventArgs)
        'Restore the selection.
        SelectionStart = selectionStartTemp
        SelectionLength = selectionLengthTemp

        MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

A side-effect of this is that you will see the text selected even when the control doesn't have focus. The `ComboBox` has no `HideSelection` property like the `TextBox` does.  If you don't like this then I'd imagine that you could find a way to make it behave like the `TextBox` does but that's a different question so I won't go into it here.

Comment: Hrm that's different to my findings as well - If in my original post you replace Handles control.Leave with control.LostFocus, shouldn't that be sufficient to return the correct result? If I debug.print the SelectionStart from within the LostFocus event, I thought that should be enough but for me, even that returns zero

Comment: I first tested `Leave` and `LostFocus` and found the property value was correct in the first handler but had been reset by the second. I then added code to remember the value in the first handler and restore it in the second. That still didn't work and when I tested `Enter` and `GotFocus` I found that the property value was correct in the first but not in the second. Once I added code to remember on `Leave` and `Enter` and to restore on `LostFocus` and `GotFocus`, everything appeared as intended from the user's perspective.

Comment: I found a peculiarity. If you press the *Tab* key to change focus, then `Leave` fires first, followed by `LostFocus`. In this instance, `Leave` returns the correct `SelectionStart` whilst `LostFocus` returns zero. If however you use the mouse to change focus, then `LostFocus` fires first, followed by `Leave`. In this instance, both `LostFocus` and `Leave` return zero, and even attempting to store the `SelectionStart` is futile because both values are zero. How does one report such a thing as a bug? Surely this isn't correct behaviour even if there is some rationale behind it.

Comment: Link below contains the reason for the different event order, but doesn't assist in providing a work around to avoid `LostFocus` from clearing the `SelectionStart` in the case of a mouse click event changing the focus. Oh well, thanks anyway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I would imagine that there would be a way to get the behaviour you want by filtering Windows messages but I don't have the time to investigate right now.  I'll get back to you if I get the chance to look more closely.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the OnLeave() sub in the class provided by @jmcilhinney it actually works nicely.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLeave(e As EventArgs)
        'Remember the current selection.
        selectionStartTemp = SelectionStart
        selectionLengthTemp = SelectionLength

        MyBase.OnLeave(e) 'this has to go last because it modifies the SelectionStart...
End Sub
```